# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am getting this error using this code, the php id variable is set, why does it show unexpected token?

```
var current_page = 1;
var id = <?php echo $id; ?>;
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $.ajax({
        'url':'get_data.php',
        'type':'post',
        'data': 'p='+current_page, 'id='+id,
        success:function(data){
            var data = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('#posts').html(data.html);
            $('#pagination').html(data.pagination);
        }
        console.log(data);  
    });
});
```

Comment: 'data' should be unique, you must concatenate current page and id, just remove the comma after current_page and add & before id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should concatenate the data query strings properly:

```
'data': 'p='+current_page +'&id='+id,
```

Or using this interface:

```
data: {p : current_page, id: id},
```

So it would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var current_page = 1;
var id = <?php echo $id; ?>;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_data.php',
        type :'POST',
        data: 'p='+current_page+'&id='+id,
        // data: {p: current_page, id: id},
        success:function(data){
            var data = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('#posts').html(data.html);
            $('#pagination').html(data.pagination);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Sidenote: You could also explicitly set `dataType: 'JSON',` so that you would not need `$.parseJSON` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong syntax for data

replace with following

```
  'data': 'p='+current_page+'&id='+id,
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
data: {
    p: current_page, 
    id: id
}
```